# Avira Antivirus acting as a virus

Tags: virus, antivirus, url-redirection

I have a Avira Antivirus installed on Windows 7. The problem is now when I click on any button or click to uninstall any program it redirects me to the Avira website where it says upgrade it for more than $40. This is the link it redirects me to:

http://www.avira.com/en/latest-threats-lp?x-a-source=AME&x-a-utoken=401b79b897a74b24bf3dd3811238824b4d6b2b58&x-a-medium=5506&x-a-version=5906&x-a-item=framer&cservices=17

How can I fix this?

Comment: Great story.  Is there a question in there anywhere?

Comment: @HopelessN00b how can I fix this?

Comment: @HopelessN00b The question was rather strongly implied.

Comment: @MattNordhoff There were actually a few possible questions in there which would have made better questions (both in general, and for this site specifically) than "halp my cimputer is borken, how do i fix it??"  I was trying to give the OP some credit by not assuming that was his question. My bad.

Comment: What do you mean with "click any button"? Click *any* button in *any* program or webpage? Or click any button in Avira?

Comment: @Anders no just clicking any button doesnt matter where. But I asked this question and the problem is immediately resolved itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem which can not be reproduced and which according to the OP already resolved itself.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich this is the exact same thing the person who created this virus wants:"close this question"

Comment: @Alex Looks like a trial period has expired for an AV package. Either uninstall it (and replace!) or buy the software and keep using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try rebooting in safe-mode and uninstall.

Tap <kbd>F8</kbd> during bootup to open Advanced Boot Options, choose safe-mode and go uninstall Avira. That is assuming you have a legacy Avira application and not a virus impersonating it.

Comment: I asked this question and the problem is immediately resolved itself.

Comment: this is the recipe to remove avira. any thoughts on removing the virus?